# how to take sum of two 1-D array(column vector)

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to add two 5 X 1 column vector. But I am getting error:
Invalid syntax

```
def sumg():
    w = np.ones((5,1))
    s = 1
    g=0
    b = np.random.rand(5,1)
    g = b + np.multiply(s,w)
 return(g)
```

I expect the output to return  b+s*w

Comment: improve your indentation and show the complete error message.

Comment: you need to indent the return statement

Answer (score 1):

You should import numpy and indent the return statement correctly.
like

```
import numpy as np
def sumg():
    w = np.ones((5,1))
    s = 1
    g=0
    b = np.random.rand(5,1)
    g = b + np.multiply(s,w)
    return(g)
```

return(g) should start where g start from .Hope it will help.